# Combining Centos 6 ISO images

Tags: centos, iso

I was wondering if I can create a single ISO image by `cat`ing two DVD ISO images together.

I have heard that this only works if the ISO is split into different parts and not two distinct ISO images, is this true? I'm looking to combine both DVD 1 and 2 for the CentOS 6 install since they don't provide a single file

Answer (score 7):

You can't `cat` the two CentOS 6 ISOs together and get the combined version of them. `cat` them would work if they had been `split` from one big ISO file, but they're two distinct ISOs created separate from one another.

If you're looking to combine the two DVDs in to one use the `mkdvdiso.sh` script from [here](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CDtoDVDMedia) and run it on a directory that contains the DVD1 and DVD2 ISOs. The script only refers to CentOS 4 and 5, but I just tested it on CentOS 6 and it works fine.

Comment: I was able to do this for CentOS 6.4 with the "mkdvdiso.sh" mentioned above. However, in my case, I needed to install "isomd5sum", "createrepo", and "mkisofs" in order to get the script to run. It also required about 16GB in the "/" partition in order to complete successfully.

Comment: turned your answer into a [how-to](http://antipaucity.com/2015/01/28/merging-centos-iso-images/#.VNufmVXF83Q) - thanks!

Answer (score -3):

This may help you:

```
mount -o loop image1.iso /path/to/mountpoint/1
mount -o loop image2.iso /path/to/mountpoint/2
mkisofs -o image.iso /path/to/mountpoint/1 /path/to/mountpoint/2
```

Comment: Without proper explanation this is guaranteed **not** to help.